# How to let google domains DynamicDNS to update ipv4 instead of ipv6 for Raspberry pi3

Tags: dns, raspberry-pi, webserver, google-domain-api

I am trying to setup personal Web Server on my Raspberry Pi3, I bought domain from Google Domains so that I could use the Dynamic DNS to let google could update IP Address of my Raspberry-Pi webserver (because my ISP provides Dynamic IP).

On my Raspberry Pi I am using crontab for periodic update by using the wget command as recommended by google. This is the 'syntax' (as adviced by google) what I am using to get the DNS update done: 
`wget https://username:password@domains.google.com/nic/update?hostname=subdomain.yourdomain.com`

**The Problem!**
Google communicates well and updates my IP but it brings up the IPv6 instead of IPv4 address of my Raspberry Pi.

**Question**: What changes should I make on my Pi so that google updates itself with my public IPv4 address rather than IPv6. Kindly note that I am a beginner, so please provide the steps I could easily follow

A big thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Add `-4` to `wget`'s parameters. Google Domains updates the Dynamic DNS synthetic record with the source IP of your request (as seen by Google servers). Thus, you need to force `wget` to make this request over IPv4 which is what the `-4` parameter does.